# TestNG Selenium Java -- java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium

If I don't use TestNG and just plain Java Selenium, all good. 
But if I use TestNG with Java Selenium , I get this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

I already put the path to the driver executeable and the compiler still complains.  Any suggestion?  Thanks.

```js
package testSuite;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
//import org.junit.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testNG 
{
 
 @Test
 public void login() throws IOException {
  System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.Driver", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = null; 
  Properties prop = new Properties(); 
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\workspace\\Selenium\\src\\testSuite\\config.properties");
  prop.load(file);
  
  System.out.println(prop.getProperty("username"));
  
  if(prop.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome")) {
   System.out.println("OKOK");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
   
  }
  driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
  
 }
  }
```

This is my properties file

```
username = 56987
password = 1234
url = www.google.com
browser = chrome
```

Comment: I cannot check now, but off the top of my head that's not how you set the path to the driver. No idea why without TestNG that works. You must create a `ChromeOptions` instance, set the path on it, and set that instance into the driver instance, I don't remember if as an arg of the constructor or through a setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. 
Just a tiny small mistake.

It should be lower case `webdriver.chrome.driver`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

instead of

```
System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.Driver", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Need to be careful with the lower or upper case.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to hardcode the path.

You can directly use  **System.getProperty("user.dir")** to go to your working directory.

And Yes use **webdriver.chrome.driver** in lower case.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the testng script from command line, you might need to add the following switch-

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=<path to chromedriver.exe>\chromedriver.exe
```